# Files Sizes M and K using command: du -sh *.a

Tags: linux, file, byte

So I am trying to see the sizes of all the .a files in a folder doing the command:

```
du -sh *.a
```

After doing this, I get both M and K. Does M = Megabytes and K = Kilobytes? Just want to make sure..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is an excerpt from `man du` on Ubuntu:

```
       -h, --human-readable
              print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
```

... and from `info du`:

```
‘-h’
‘--human-readable’
     Append a size letter to each size, such as ‘M’ for mebibytes.
     Powers of 1024 are used, not 1000; ‘M’ stands for 1,048,576 bytes.
     This option is equivalent to ‘--block-size=human-readable’.  Use
     the ‘--si’ option if you prefer powers of 1000.
```